# The German keywords with high monthly searches and good ranks in Google haven't any traffic

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, google-ads, traffic

I have some questions about German SEO. Some words we are optimizing have high monthly search, and good rank in Google.de, but these pages focusing on the keywords don't have any traffic. What's wrong with it?

PS: The keywords'monthly searches data is from Google Adwords, and the rank is checked manually (with German IP).

Comment: There is a difference between what Google reports as a popular search term and a valuable search term. Generally, the more used search terms have little value. Create content and please, please, please do not chase keywords. That is not how search works. It is about whole language, valuable content, and effectively marketing your content. Google, for example, does not make direct search term matches. Any apparent search term match is only highlighting search terms after a long list of algorithms and semantic analysis. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I saw these kids set up a lemonade stand down the street. Why haven't they sold any lemonade?

My point is, just cause you throw something out there doesn't mean people will come flocking to it. Do they have a reason to do so? Remember, your page is one of billions and billions with similar and same content. Why do you think anyone knows it's there?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not using the Adwords Keyword Planner tool correctly.  When you type a keyword into it, it defaults to "broad match".   This means that it will show you how many people search for your term and *all related concepts*.  From a practical perspective, that makes it look like there will be much more traffic on your term than actually exists.

Instead of using broad match, you need to set the tool to "exact match" mode.  That way it only shows people who searched for exactly what you are ranking for.

Actually, it looks like Google took the exact match functionality out of this tool.   It doesn't look like the Adword Keyword Planner is useful for estimating search volume any more.   The closest thing they have now is a setting for "Only show ideas closely related to my search terms":

[image]